# Dynamic import of webpackChunkName

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, javascript-import

I'm new to webpack and I wonder if there's a way to add dynamic chunk name and path in an import. I tried doing this, but it's wrong

`import(/* webpackChunkName: "${file_name}"*/ './modules/${js_path}')`

or

`import(/* webpackChunkName: "'+file_name+'"*/ './modules/'+js_path+'')`

fyi, I can't use [request] as webpack chunck name because it's including the folder name.

I tried searching for similar problem, but not success. Please help.

TIA :)